# Adding data to a data.frame inside a renderText statement

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm using shiny and I've been trying to add data to a data.frame using userinputs (and when the goButton is activated) within a renderText set.

My current code:

```
output$text3 <- renderText({
      if (input$goButton == 1){
      "New Patient Information Added"
      newpatientrow <- data.frame(input$newptnum, input$newptsy, 0)
      names(newpatientrow)[1]<- "patientlist"
      names(newpatientrow)[2]<- "patientsy"
      names(newpatientrow)[3]<- "patientdx"
      print(newpatientrow)
      patientdata <- rbind(patientdata,newpatientrow)}
```

I've been having a lot of trouble, even defining a function outside the shinyserver () doesn't work.